# Cant host discord bot (js) on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to host a bot on heroku (written using node and discord js). The bot itself is working since I can run it locally with no issues but heroku doesn't seem to like it. I've been getting the same error every time I tried to deploy it. I've changed the Procfile file to a worker instead of web application, I have pushed everything + restarted but can't seem to get it to work. Any help?

```
2020-01-28T11:31:46.007810+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-01-28T11:31:48.995011+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-01-28T11:31:49.818228+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-01-28T11:31:52.030152+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-01-28T11:31:52.006456+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886594+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An invalid token was provided.
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886618+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RESTMethods.js:34:54
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886621+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886623+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RESTMethods.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RESTMethods.js:33:12)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886625+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:280:30)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886627+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:45:8)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886629+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886631+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886633+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886635+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.886637+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.887556+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
2020-01-28T11:31:51.887666+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Hello, check you bot token `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An invalid token was provided.`

Comment: So turns out the gitignore file prevented a .env file from being pushed which was why the bot crashed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just the error it is hard to know the exact problem, but I think that you might have given a wrong Token for the bot, check if you didn't ignore the file containing the token.
If you are using a .env file for your token, then you can define environment variables on the app on Heroku.